# Optaplanner Employee Rostering with VRPTW

Tags: optaplanner

I am working on a use case which is a combination between the Nurse Rostering example and a VRP problem. In isolation, I understand and can tweak both to a certain extent, but I'm not quite sure how to merge them.

To illustrate my use case further, I am trying to schedule nurses (considering skills, contract, and preferences) to patients homes, located within a 20-40 mile radius.

As an example, a nurse with the "insulin" skill would need to travel to a patient, arriving within a certain time window, perform a task for 15 mins, then travel to another patient, perform the same task, and continue until its 8 hour shift is complete. There are multiple skills and tasks to be considered.

I reviewed the Nurse Rostering example and it is a great fit for my use case, but I don't see how to modify it to account for traveling between "shift locations". The VRPTW example is again a great fit, but it does not account for skills, contracts, and preferences.

Any thoughts on how to go about modelling this problem would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even if my answer can possibly be still too general for you to use, I would combine both models in a way more or less similar to the following :

- use the nurse rostering example's model as the start point
- in that model, include all intervention locations's properties; this includes at least : the intervention location data, the time window in which to intervene at the location, and the needed skill(s) needed to do the intervention locally
- combine both model's constraints, not to forget *at least* the constraint(s) penalising a visit to a location with an insufficient skillset (sounds like a hard constraint) and the constraint(s) penalising lengthy travel times/distances.

I also suspect a more intensive usage of the shadow variables due to the combination of both models.

May still sound too vague, but that would be the direction where I would work towards.